# Django different backends for different devices

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication

I've stumbled upon a weird and non-standard problem.
My Django app is separated into two parts

1. standard web Django template rendering part where users are
   authenticated using username and password and then by
   sessions.
2. mobile app + REST API part where users are Authenticated using username, password
   **and unique installation identifier stored in app keychain** and then JWT's

This is a little bit tricky as don't want mobile "smart" users to authenticate using web browser without the aforementioned mobile identifier (even if they will get only json responses instead of full website - I don't want that). So the question narrows to:

How to authenticate User using only username and password while he's on web app **and at the same time** not authenticate this user when he calls the api JWT obtain token enpoint with only username and password (wihout giving installation identifier)

I have additional already backend written but I don't want to expose my app to unauthorized access

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit?  Are there 2 types of users with some sort of flag on the account saying where they can log in?  The statement about "aformentioned id" is confusing.

Comment: Yea so there are (kind of) 2 types of user (only one model with role field separation). Users with role 'child' can only access mobile application, and should not be allowed on web app. Users with role 'parent' can register and log into web app but only ones that paid for the mobile app should also have access to it (using the installation id)

Comment: Your comment also mixes multiple questions/issues.  For example, I'm not sure what do with "only the paid people" or why I would even need to know that.  A simplified version of your question would be "I have 2 user roles on my user model, and want to control what parts of the app they can access.  {here is my general setup, views vs api, login methods needed, etc} ".  I'll do my best to answer, but the actual issue is fuzzy

Comment: Just write a custom backend that enforces your web auth logic, since that issues a session key.  For the rest api, write a custom jwt login enforces the other rules, and only let the rest api use JWT?  It would be double login, but that doesn't seem like an issue since one is mobile and would need to anyway.  Thats the simplest.  Outside of that, you need custom (but still simple) DRF permissions_classes